# Text input in display:flex div does not get smaller past some point, why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't seem to make my text input get shorter.. 
which is making my button seen as cut.

(I use `overflow: hidden` because I don't want the external div to grow.)

What am I missing here?

```html
<div style="max-width:105px; display:flex; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="" style="flex:1; display:flex">
       <input style="flex:2; min-width:0px" >
       <button style="flex:2; min-width:0px">
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2xapnu9k/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there is a circular definition:

- The size of the `#inner-wrapper` depends on the size of the input and the button via `min-width: auto`.
- The sizes of the input and the button depend on the size of `#inner-wrapper` via flex properties.

Therefore, `#inner-wrapper` is sized according to the intrinsic width of the button and the input.

If you don't want that, you can break the circular definition manually:

- Make `#inner-wrapper` ignore the sizes of its contents

  ```css
  #inner-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  #outer-wrapper {
    max-width: 105px;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #inner-wrapper {
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 0;
    display: flex;
  }
  input, button {
    min-width: 0;
    flex: 2;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="outer-wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrapper">
      <input />
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Make the input and button ignore their intrinsic width.

  ```css
  input, button {
    width: 0;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  #outer-wrapper {
    max-width: 105px;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #inner-wrapper {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
  }
  input, button {
    width: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    flex: 2;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="outer-wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrapper">
      <input />
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: For me, using ```width: 0``` only for the input element alone did the trick for me, no ```min-width: 0``` necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Consider applying the `max-width` to the parent (not the grand parent) of the form controls ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2xapnu9k/21/)).

Also note that the default minimum size of flex items is the size of their content. An alternative solution to your problem would be applying `min-width:0` to your inner div ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2xapnu9k/24/)).

More details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/3597276

Comment: the max-width is applied to the grand parent just to show that my parent is growing.

your answered helped me to realize it is the parent that is causing me trouble with min width. thanks !